# Highlight entire row instead of cell

Tags: r, openxlsx

The following code here highlights cells when the Count is more than 32, what I want is it to highlight the entire row

```
df = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 15, 60, 23, 25, 60, 50, 18, 31))

wb = createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Master")
writeDataTable(wb, "Master", df, tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")

yellow_style = createStyle(fgFill = "#FFFF00")
y = which(colnames(df) == "Count")
x = which(abs(df$Count) > 32)
addStyle(wb, sheet = "Master", style = yellow_style, rows = x+1, col = y)
saveWorkbook(wb, "Master.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight rows up to certain column use `1:n` index:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb = createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Master")
writeDataTable(wb, "Master", df, tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")

yellow_style = createStyle(fgFill = "#FFFF00")

x = which(abs(df$Count) > 32) + 1
y = 1:which(colnames(df) == "Count") # <==== here, 1 to up to column "count"

addStyle(wb, sheet = "Master", style = yellow_style,
         rows = x, col = y, gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "Master.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

---

To highlight the entire row, use some big number for columns:

```
wb = createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Master")
writeDataTable(wb, "Master", df, tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")

yellow_style = createStyle(fgFill = "#FFFF00")

x = which(abs(df$Count) > 32) + 1
y = which(colnames(df) == "Count"):10 # <==== here, I am using 10 as example

addStyle(wb, sheet = "Master", style = yellow_style,
         rows = x, col = y, gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "Master.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

There is an open feature request at [GitHub #439](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/439)

Comment: Yup, works well! I changed it to 
y = 1:which(colnames(df) == "Count") 
and it highlights the entire row. Cheers